# Add a class and remove the current one so that a button in J Query may be re-used for a different function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a fourteen year old trying to cope with a fairly new language so please bear with me. I made a quick html doc so that I can express my problem as clearly as possible.

If you run the snippet, you can see that by clicking the menu button the body is pushed 285 pixels from the left, and the menu is shifted to 0px from -285px.

I want to be able to click on the menu button again and shift the body back to 0, and the menu back to -285. Please look under the J Query to see the processes I've tried so far.

```js
var main = function(){
    $('.menu_button').click(function(){
    $('.menu').animate({left: '0px'}, 200);
    $('body').animate({left: '285px'}, 200);
    $('.menu_button').addClass('menu_button_active').removeClass('menu_button');    
    });
    
    $('.menu_button_active').click(function(){
        $('.menu').animate({left: '-285px'}, 200);
        $('body').animate({left: '0px'}, 200);
        $('.menu_button_active').addClass('menu_button').removeClass('menu_button_active');
    });
};

$(document).ready(main);
/* At first, I tried to just plug in the same class name in the second function, however I 
quickly realized that by doing so the menu will automatically close since both functions 
will run at the same time. 

My understanding is that in order for the function to being separately, the menu button 
would have to have a different class at the time of the click. So, I tried using
 toggleClass to remove the menu_button class while at the same time adding the
 menu_button_active class so that on click, the menu_button_active class can act as the 
same button, but used for a different function (closing the menu.) Perhaps my understanding
 of what the toggleClass method was used for was flawed, however here is the code anyway to 
show you what I had done. 

$('.menu_button').toggleClass("menu_button" "menu_button_active");
in place of
$('.menu_button').addClass('menu_button_active').removeClass('menu_button');
(this doesn't work)

So, my final method is shown above. By separately adding and removing the class I don't see 
why it doesn't work after working out what the js would be doing. First the menu_button 
would be clicked and the page is shifted, afterwards the menu_button would have a different
 class name, so that it can be called by the menu_button_active function, which then 
changes the class again so that the menu button can open again and so on.
*/
```

```css
#first_row {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3em;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #888888;
}

#sec2 {
    background-color: #2CD148;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

body {
    left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3em;
    background-color: #404040;
    position: fixed;
}

.menu {
  background-color: black;
  left: -285px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 285px;
}

.menu_button {
    width: 4em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu_button_active {
    width: 4em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu_row {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0.25em;
    margin-top: 0.5625em;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2CD148;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Samer | Welcome</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="media_items/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="media_items/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Interactive.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="menu"></div>
        <div class = "menu_button">
            <div class = "menu_row"></div>
            <div class = "menu_row"></div>
            <div class = "menu_row"></div>
        </div>
        <span></span>
    </header>
    <div id = first_row>
        <section id = "sec1"></section>
        <section id = "sec2"></section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What's the flaw in this logic?

Comment: `$('.menu_button_active').click(…)` – you don’t have an element with the class `menu_button_active` in your document at the moment this code is executed. You’ll need to use event delegation if you want to make it work this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define your class from javascript so you need to attach event to your class name. see http://api.jquery.com/on/

```js
var main = function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.menu_button', function(){
    $('.menu').animate({left: '0px'}, 200);
    $('body').animate({left: '285px'}, 200);
    $(this).addClass('menu_button_active').removeClass('menu_button');    
    });
    
    $('body').on('click', '.menu_button_active', function(){
        $('.menu').animate({left: '-285px'}, 200);
        $('body').animate({left: '0px'}, 200);
        $(this).addClass('menu_button').removeClass('menu_button_active');
    });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
#first_row {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3em;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #888888;
}

#sec2 {
    background-color: #2CD148;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

body {
    left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3em;
    background-color: #404040;
    position: absolute;
}

.menu {
  background-color: black;
  left: -285px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 285px;
}

.menu_button {
    width: 4em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu_button_active {
    width: 4em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu_row {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0.25em;
    margin-top: 0.5625em;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2CD148;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Samer | Welcome</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="media_items/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="media_items/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Interactive.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="menu"></div>
        <div class = "menu_button">
            <div class = "menu_row"></div>
            <div class = "menu_row"></div>
            <div class = "menu_row"></div>
        </div>
        <span></span>
    </header>
    <div id = first_row>
        <section id = "sec1"></section>
        <section id = "sec2"></section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You lost .menu_button_active, I can't see in nowhere of the code.Your second click function never runs, because the trigger button is missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
var main = function(){

     $('body').on('click', '.menu_button', function(){
   // $('.menu_button').click(function(){        
       $('.menu').animate({left: '0px'}, 200);
        $('body').animate({left: '285px'}, 200);
        $('.menu_button').addClass('menu_button_active').removeClass('menu_button');    
    });
       $('body').on('click', '.menu_button_active', function(){
        $('.menu').animate({left: '-285px'}, 200);
        $('body').animate({left: '0px'}, 200);
                $('.menu_button_active').addClass('menu_button').removeClass('menu_button_active');
    });


};
$(document).ready(main);
```